# How to create a django admin model inline for a group object connecting two other objects?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-admin

I have the following Django models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team=models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For modeling a simple team of multiple persons.

Now I would like to be able to edit teams in the Django admin interface with an inline. I tried:

```
class PersonInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person

class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    inlines = [PersonInline]
```

But then I get inlines that allow me to add new Persons, but want to have inlines that allow me to select existing persons (with an optional "add" button).

How can I get inlines that allow to select existing objects?